# Update Google Map automatically when Google spreadsheet is updated?

Tags: google-maps

I'm using [Google Maps Engine Lite](https://mapsengine.google.com/map/?) and placing markers on the map from a Google spreadsheet. At the moment I'm importing these manually into a layer.

Is there a way to automatically update the pins when the spreadsheet is updated?

There very little out there on this or is it because this needs to be done via the API with a coded solution?

Comment: Just learned that Google Fusion Tables was discontinued in 2019. :(

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/90552/3317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found that using Google Fusion tables solved this problem so that when that was updated, so was the map.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Google Spreadsheets add-on called [Geosheets](http://www.geosheets.com) to create your map.  That way your map will automatically update in realtime whenever data changes in your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

this GeoSheets looked cool at first, but the documentation is either wrong or it is mapping incorrectly. I gave it 20 addresses in Florida, and it placed them all over the world. Also after testing for 30 minutes I ran in to the daily free limit.